# Can't test with coverage in Android Studio and ObjectBox bacause of "cannot find symbol" compilation errors in auto-generated files

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, objectbox, objectbox-android

I'm using Android studio 4.1.1, ObjectBox 3.0.1 and Kotlin 1.5.10.

The tests run nicely when I hit the *run* button on the test class or run `./gradlew :app-core:test`, but when I click on `Run X with coverage` the tests run through, I'm shown

```
Project Is out of Date: Project class files are out of date. Would you like to recompile? The refusal to do it will result in incomplete coverage information
```

If I click on `Cancel` the coverage report in the background disappears (so I can't read the coverage info, also there is no coverage info left of the code lines in the editor).

If I click `OK` compilation is started and I get a compilation error in a ObjectBox-generated file `SomeEntityCursor`:

```
Error:(14, 49) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SomeEntity
```

The same is happening in other generated classes (see details below). But bottom line is that the generated code seems to not be able to see my entity class. Noteworthy: the generated code is in the same module as the entity class.

Fyi, `SomeEntity` simply looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class SomeEntity(@Id var id: Long = 0, ...)
```

Strangely, sometimes it manages to compile, but certainly *not* if I do a `Clean project` before!

Here is the full output (I'm sorry for the inconsistencies between example package names and the ones in the log, I hope it doesn't make any difference!):

```
Information:Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.4.32 (JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'SomeApp.common.common-android'
Information:javac 1.8.0_242-release was used to compile java sources
Information:11/8/21 2:46 PM - Build completed with 21 errors and 3 warnings in 8 s 772 ms
/Users/xxx/Documents/Programming/SomeApp/common/common-android/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/somecompany/someapp/common/android/persistence/SomeEntityCursor.java
    Error:Error:line (14)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SomeEntity
    Error:Error:line (34)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntityCursor
    Error:Error:line (44)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntityCursor
    Error:Error:line (16)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntityCursor
    Error:Error:line (18)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntityCursor.Factory
/Users/xxx/Documents/Programming/SomeApp/common/common-android/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/somecompany/someapp/common/android/persistence/SomeEntity_.java
    Error:Error:line (15)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SomeEntity
    Error:Error:line (93)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (23)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (27)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (34)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (37)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (40)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (44)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (50)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (63)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (73)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (78)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (83)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (88)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
    Error:Error:line (95)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_.SomeEntityIdGetter
    Error:Error:line (23)java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SomeEntity
  location: class com.comecompany.someapp.common.android.persistence.SomeEntity_
```

I couldn't find any info info on the problem on the web, unfortunately, so any hint is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you try with the latest stable Android Studio release and Android plugin to make sure this isn't a bug in the tooling that was already fixed?

Comment: I installed a new Android Studio version, created an empty project with updated tools and added module after module. Same problem. But it's noteworthy that the problem starts ONLY when the `app` module (including all other modules) is added. I have it on GitHub (privately, I can give you access if you want). There are two commits, one where it works and one where it doesn't anymore @Uwe-ObjectBox

Comment: OK, have this same message with a simple Kotlin Android project (not for a Java-only Android project). But if I always click OK the coverage report stays visible. Not sure how to fix this, yet (and if this is even an issue with our tooling).

Comment: Could you create a bug report for that? You have a simple project to reproduce the problem. If not, can you upload it somewhere so I can reference it and create the bug report? @Uwe-ObjectBox

Comment: The problem in my case is also that if not properly recompiled, the coverage report is not showing any numbers in the respective module, btw.

Comment: I used https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/tree/main/android-app-kotlin and added a simple unit test to it.